# Organizing extensions in Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Swift we usually use extensions as a way to organize methods in separate blocks and even files. This makes code much cleaner but it also allows us to do some tricks such as:

```
class API {}

extension API {
    class Lists{}
}

extension Lists {
    class Posts {

        func latest() -> [Post] {
            // get latest posts from a REST api
        }

    }
}
```

We can put any of the extension blocks in a separate file and it works perfectly in Swift.
Now one do the following to get the latest posts from the API in a clean way

```
let posts = API.Lists.Posts.latest()
```

Trying to convert that code into Kotlin I used [SwiftKotlin](https://github.com/angelolloqui/SwiftKotlin/) converter tool that I thought that might work but it doesn't compile as It seems to be invalid:

```
class API {}

class API.Lists {}

class Lists.Posts {
    companion object {

        fun latest() {
            // get posts
        }

    }
}
```

So I came up with the following that works fine and also compiles but it's not suitable for my case as methods can be quite long and I can't afford to have them all in one class in one file and I don't know how I can split them in multiple files.

```
class API {

    class Lists {

        class Posts {
            companion object {
                fun latest() {

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put an extension on a companion object, you [can write](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions)

```
fun API.Lists.Posts.Companion.latest() ...
```

You still need

```
class API {
    class Lists {
        class Posts {
            companion object {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in a single file, but extensions can be defined elsewhere.

Comment: I just tested this and it actually works perfectly. I didn't see any mention of something like this in the documentation but this is a great method.

Comment: I've linked the relevant documentation, though?

Comment: I couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to mimic usage of these calls, you can use objects, like this for example:

```
object ApiPosts {
    fun latest() {}
}

object ApiLists {
    val Posts = ApiPosts
}

object API {
    val Lists = ApiLists
}

API.Lists.Posts.latest()
```

But this is really not a Kotlin way, and in common case it's a bad practice to write in a language the way it's not supposed to.

Comment: The usage is similar to the Swift version and that's a good thing for me but in your opinion would you suggest your way or the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to just extend the inner classes with normal functions not static ones (companion):

```
class ParentClass {

    class InnerClass {

    }

}
```

And in any other file you could do:

```
fun ParentClass.InnerClass.instanceMember() {

}
```

And for usage:

```
ParentClass.InnerClass().instanceMember()
```

Of course this isn't exactly like the Swift version but it's close enough.

Comment: I wanted to keep the usage the same way between platforms (iOS and Android) but I suppose this is as good as it's gonna get.